# Textboxes inside gridview validation

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview in which I have 100 rows of Textboxes. All textboxes have same id 'TxtEmpcode'. User enters data in some rows of gridview. How do I validate textboxes such that one Employee code is entered only once in textboxes.  This is to avoid duplicate entry of data. Suppose a user enters Employee code '1234', this should not allowed in other rows of textboxes. If they enter, a message should appear as 'Employee Code has already been entered'.

Can anyone tell how to achieve this?

```html
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" style="margin-left: 23px; margin-top: 11px;" Width="420px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="213px"  >
               <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
             <Columns>
           
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Code">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmpcode" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TxtId_TextChanged" AutoPostBack ="true"   ></asp:TextBox>  
            </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Which framework of asp.net you are using is it 4.0  or higher?

Comment: Yes... It is 4.0 or higher i'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use logic of it as per your requirement.

```
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script>

    function IsValidTest(Control) {

        name = Control.name;

        var list = document.getElementById("TxtEmpcode");

        var contents = $("[id=TxtEmpcode]");

        var TextboxId = name;

        var Txtbox = document.getElementsByName(name);
        var TextboxValue = Txtbox[0].value;

        for (i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) 
        { 

            var currenttextboxName=contents[i].name;
            var currenttextboxValue=contents[i].value;


            //Compare currently changed value with existing values in other textboxes
            if (name != currenttextboxName && currenttextboxValue == TextboxValue)
            {
                alert('Employee Code has already been entered');
                Txtbox[0].value = '';

                return false;
            }        
        }

        return true;
    }

</script>

    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 23px; margin-top: 11px;"
            Width="420px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="#333333"
            GridLines="None" Height="213px">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee Code">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TxtEmpcode" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" ClientIDMode="Static" onchange="javascript: return IsValidTest(this);"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>        

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: I encounterd one more problem. I have written Ontextchanged function for textbox. This is not firing after writing this javascript function. When employee Code is entered in textbox, other employee related information is populated in other read only textboxes.

Comment: In my code Ontextchanged  is not there..so check whether your code have it not..If yes then please remember that Ontextchanged  will get called only for valid non duplicate values...Also everything is fine the check whether there are any java script errors or not (using developer tool F12 key)

Comment: Also in stack overflow site it is always nice to appreciate efforts of others by upvoting or accepting answers..If you think this has helped you or will help others in future (always accept most efficient answers) .. :)

Comment: Hey Sagar, I upvoted your answer even before you told. But Im new to stackoverflow. It asks me to earn minimum 15 reputation to upvote.

Comment: I did appreciate your efforts dude. I have joined stackoverflow very few days back.  By the way ,Can you pls tell me solution to my problem?

Comment: Thanks..I have already mentioned few points in my comment...please check my first comment of this series..

Comment: @Vinay - You can accept the answer. There is no reputation criteria for that, Just click the tick mark, Check this link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work